# How can I get mentions about my post on Twitter with python app by using the twitter api?

Tags: python, twitter

I am going to get all mentions about my post by using python package-tweepy.
Here is an example code I tried to run.

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = "my_key"
consumer_secret = "my_key"
access_token = "token"
access_token_secret = "token"

auth = tweepy.OAuth1BearerHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
client = tweepy.Client(auth=auth)

query = 'news'
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=["text"], max_results=10)
for tweet in tweets.data:
    print(tweet.text)
```

But I got this error.

> raise ExceptionType(
> twython.exceptions.TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

How to solve this?
My account is a new one
Thanks

Comment: You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. Depending on your access tier this might not include searching for recent tweets. So, if you need access to that endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: [https://twittercommunity.com/t/understanding-the-error-453-you-currently-have-access-to-a-subset-of-twitter-api-v2-endpoints/200361](https://twittercommunity.com/t/understanding-the-error-453-you-currently-have-access-to-a-subset-of-twitter-api-v2-endpoints/200361)

Comment: Could you tell me how to change my access level? Thanks

Comment: From [https://developer.twitter.com/](https://developer.twitter.com/) you'd go to the Developer Portal -> Products -> Twitter API v2 and there you can view the Free, Basic and Pro tiers, see the exact API end points available in each (don't trust the description texts, check the actual API endpoint lists) and also subscribe to a one.